# Terminating loops

Tags: c, loops

So I have a function that is supposed to find the mode of a set of data input by a user. I believe there is a problem with how I terminate my loops, using the `'\0'` character, but I'm not sure. Even if that is the problem, I don't know how to fix it. Any advice appreciated.

```
int mode(int input[]){
int array[70]={0},i=0,j=0,i2=0,j2=0;


while (input[i]!='\0'){
    j=input[i];
    array[j]=array[j]+1;
    i++;
    }

while (array[i2]!='\0'){
    if (array[i2]>j2){
        j2=array[i2];
        i2++;
    }
    else{
    i2++;
    }
}
return j2;
}
```

Comment: If `input` is an `int` array, then why would you have a character `'\0'`? The Nul terminator is strings, which is C are `char` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you will know how many entries are in the user's input, so your `mode()` function will be better off as `int mode(int num, int input[])`.  Your code assumes that the values in the input array will be in the range 1..69 without checking.  It is odd (though technically legitimate) to write `'\0'` instead of 0.  Your second loop stops when it comes across a zero count. It does that immediately because `array[0]` is never set to anything other than zero.

I'd write the loops as `for` loops, whether using a 'zero as sentinel' or 'explicit count'.

```
int mode(int input[])
{
    int array[70];
    for (int i = 0; input[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        int value = input[i];
        if (value > 0 && value < 70)
            array[value]++;
    }

    int m_value = array[1];
    for (int j = 2; j < 70; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] > m_value)
            m_value = array[j];
    }

    return m_value;
}
```

The only difference for the counted version that I recommend is changing the termination condition of the first loop from `input[i] != 0;` to `i < num;`.